# How can I operate on \1 in sed (or $1 in awk)?

Tags: awk, sed, pipe, replace

I have file with several lines. Each with a timestamp followed by text:

```
1534888050 some text
1534888051 some more text
1534888052 text
```

... and want to convert the timestamp to a readable format, while keeping the text. The result shall be:

```
Tue Aug 21 21:47:30 UTC 2018 some text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:31 UTC 2018 some more text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:32 UTC 2018 text
```

`date -d@"${somedate}"` converts the timestamp itself correctly.

Now I want the same with one filter / pipe command through **sed** or **awk** (or any other common command).

This does not work, but roughly explains what I am thinking of:

```
echo '1534888050 some text' | sed "s#^\([0-9]*\) .*#`date -d@\1`#g"
```

(The `\1` is the matched timestamp)

**Any way to achieve this in an elegant manner ?**

Answer (score 3):

The [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) package is great for such things, specifically the `dconv` tool.  (When installed on Ubuntu systems the command is available as `dateutils.dconv`.)

Here is an illustration:

```
$ cat testfile.txt 
1534888050 some text
1534888051 some more text
1534888052 text
$ dateutils.dconv -i '%s' -f '%a %b %d %T %Y' -S <testfile.txt 
Tue Aug 21 21:47:30 2018 some text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:31 2018 some more text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:32 2018 text
$ dateutils.dconv -i '%s' -f '%F %T' -S <testfile.txt 
2018-08-21 21:47:30 some text
2018-08-21 21:47:31 some more text
2018-08-21 21:47:32 text
$
```

The `-S` flag is key; it tells the tool to operate in "sed mode" and include the non-date text in the output.

The `-i` flag specifies the input date format and the `-f` flag specifies the output date format.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU awk (aka `gawk`) you can use its built-in `strftime` function to convert an epoch time to a format of your choice:

```
$ TZ=UTC gawk '{$1 = strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", $1)} 1' file
Tue Aug 21 21:47:30 UTC 2018 some text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:31 UTC 2018 some more text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:32 UTC 2018 text
```

You could also use perl with the `POSIX` module:

```
$ TZ=UTC perl -MPOSIX -alne '
    print join " ", strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", localtime shift @F), @F
  ' file
Tue Aug 21 21:47:30 UTC 2018 some text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:31 UTC 2018 some more text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:32 UTC 2018 text
```

Although the GNU implementation of `sed` does have an `e` modifier to allow execution of external commands, it operates on the whole pattern space - making it rather cumbersome to use in practice.

Answer (score 0):

In awk you can use

```
awk '{ cmd = "date -d@" $1; cmd | getline date; close (cmd); $1 = date; print $0; }'
```

To restrict to numeric values, check for the pattern of only digits:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ { cmd = "date -d@" $1; cmd | getline $1; close (cmd); print $0; }'
```

Comment: Which could be shortened to `awk '{ cmd = "date -d@" $1; cmd | getline $1; close (cmd)} 1'`

Comment: Interesting. How would I ensure this is only applied on a `^[0-9]+` pattern? (There are lines that don't start with a timestamp that cause errors with this.)

Comment: See the example.

Answer (score 0):

Using Awk:

```
{
  "date -d @" $1 | getline $1
}
1
```

Result:

```
Tue, Aug 21, 2018  4:47:30 PM some text
Tue, Aug 21, 2018  4:47:31 PM some more text
Tue, Aug 21, 2018  4:47:32 PM text
```

Answer (score 0):

If sed is a must, use GNU sed with:

```
$ sed -e 'h;s/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/date -ud @\1/;e' -e 'x;s//\2/;x;G;s/\n/ /' infile.txt
Tue Aug 21 21:47:30 UTC 2018 some text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:31 UTC 2018 some more text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:32 UTC 2018 text
```

Otherwise, the shell could do:

```
$ TZ=UTC0 bash -c 'while read a b; do printf '\''%(%c)T %s\n'\'' "$a" "$b"; done <infile'
Tue 21 Aug 2018 09:47:30 PM UTC some text
Tue 21 Aug 2018 09:47:31 PM UTC some more text
Tue 21 Aug 2018 09:47:32 PM UTC text
```

Or, better yet, use awk:

```
$ awk '{c="date -ud @" $1;c|getline $1;close(c)}1' infile.txt
Tue Aug 21 21:47:30 UTC 2018 some text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:31 UTC 2018 some more text
Tue Aug 21 21:47:32 UTC 2018 text
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to realize is that `GNU sed` replaces the whole of the pattern space with the result of comnand evaluation in the RHS of the `s///e`. So to accommodate that behavior, we make use of the `echo + date` commands combo as shown :

```
 sed -e  's/^\([1-9][0-9]*\)\(.*\)/echo "`date -d@\"\1\"`\2"/e'  input-file.txt
```

And with `Perl`, it is simple in that, what is matched on the LHS is only replaced on the RHS, as one would intuitively expect also:

```
  perl -pe 's/(\d+)/qx(date -d@"$1") =~ s|\n||r/e'  input-file.txt
```